# Scene in upper right corner of OpenGL window without using glOrtho

Tags: opengl, rendering

Essentially, I'm rendering a raw buffer of pixels onto a texture, which is wrapped onto a quad.

My GL initiation code:

```
void INITOGL(int xres, int yres){
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
glClearDepth(1);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
//gluOrtho2D(0, xres, 0, yres);
}
```

Render loop code:

```
void RenderCycle(){
    register MSG msg = {0};
    while(1){
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        //glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);//GL_LINEAR
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE/*GL_DECAL*/);

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, framebuffer);//viewport virtual size

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_B

IT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f( 800, 0, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f( 800, 600, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f( 0, 600, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
   }
```

The resize function:

```
void ResizeViewport(int height, int width){
    if(!height)height++;
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    //gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    //gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

The buffer that holds the RGB data is just set to red using a for loop, and this is the output.

[image: Window during rendering red image]
Have I improperly set my viewport, not scaled something correctly, or am I just completely missing something? If you need any more information, just ask. I have given all of the opengl sided code, the rest shouldn't make a difference. In theory, it should render red to the entire screen.

Comment: Until you're ready to look at how projections work: `gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)`

Comment: I've got a pretty good handle on projecting, but I was unaware that glOrtho had that functionality. I was always told to use the resolution and it would do the rest... :| Thanks.